# Is there a difference between /.*N.*/ and /N/ (in regular expressions of MongoDB)

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'd like to find documents in my MongoDB that contain a capital N in the name-field. The following two searches both return the correct result.

```
db.col.find({name: /N/})
db.col.find({name: /.*N.*/})
```

So far I always used regular expressions as in the first `find()`-statement, in the belief that the `.*` were added, if I don't not use `^` or `$`. But I never really **knew** if there is a difference or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is quicker than the second.
Here is a benchmark in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my @data = (
    'jkhfq lqksjdfh N lmkjqf N kjlh',
    'NNNNNNNNNN',
    'lkjh vuzyd vuyr gdqhgsjkhdg',
);
my $count = -2;
cmpthese($count, {
    'anchor' => sub {
        my @match = grep{/^.*N.*$/} @data;;
    },
    'simple' => sub {
        my @match = grep { /N/ } @data;
    },
});
```

**Result:**

```
           Rate anchor simple
anchor 378332/s     --   -28%
simple 521907/s    38%     --
```

The regex `/N/` is 38% faster than `/^.*N.*$/`.

Comment: This should also hold in MongoDB's regexp engine - the first regexp will run faster than the second.

Comment: I made a ranking of other Regexps: `/N/` < `/^.*+N.*+$/` < `/.*?N.*?/` < `/.*N.*/` < `/^.*N.*$/` < `/^.*?N.*?$/` < `/.*+N.*+/`.